# Is it possible to load only valid data to a pydantic model?

Tags: pydantic

I'm trying to migrate input validation from marshmallow to pydantic for data validation as pydantic is used elsewhere in the project. I've got a bit stuck though, as the current code has the option to return only valid data extracted from the marshmallow ValidationError, like this:

```
try:
    MyMarshmallowSchema().load(payload)
    return payload
except ValidationError as vld_fail:
    return vld_fail.valid_data
```

Is it possible to do something equivalent with pydantic?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case but one idea to circumvent the issue *may be to add pre validators if there are a small number of fields that may be failing and then if it doesn't match a condition, nullify them.

```
from typing import Any, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, Required, validator


class School(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=10)
    age: int = Field(Required)
    
    @validator('name', pre=True)
    def validate_name(cls: Any, name: str) -> str:
        if len(name) > 10: return None
        return name

data = School(**{"name": "test123456789", "age": 12})

print(data.dict(exclude_none=True))


----  OUTPUT  -----
{'age': 12}
```